Is the Bassline of "I Know It's Over" by The Smiths an Example of Swing Rhythm?
As a beginner in music theory, I'm still trying to get my head around some rhythm concepts. Is the bassline of "I Know It's Over" by The Smiths an example of swing rhythm? If not, how does it differ?

The short answer is "yes"; a longer answer is "what constitutes 'swing'?" The word ultimately refers back to the swing genre, and this song isn't swing music. But it does have that "long-short" pattern. One of the easiest ways to see it in action is to listen to real swing music while looking at the notation and see how what look like equal 8th notes on the page come out unequal.

...or look at the time signature (x/8 or triplet feel)

@Andy has it right taking Swing = long short patterns. An easy way to check is to upload it into a DAW (maybe separate the bass stem first) and use a click track to check that the second note is not exactly 'on' the beat but delayed somewhat. This song uses the delay just like lots of other 'romantic' pop songs.

Long-short in the bassline can also be a shuffle, which is different from swing.  It's common in swing to have "doo-BAH-doo-BAH" in the melody and "ding-dinga-ding" in the drums (on the ride cymbal) but straight quarters a walking bassline.

The overall rhythm of the piece is Slow Rock Ballad instead of Swing.  Looking at the first page of this MuseScore arrangement by Mike Esfahani, it's notated in 6/8, instead of Swing's usual 4/4.  But if as @Laurence suggested it's notated in 12/8 (4 beats), it does look like a slow Swing, especially since when you notice the drums, there are slight emphasis on beats 2 and 4.
But Swing has other characteristics that only the 2th and 4th beats usually have triplets (see example here).  Compare with a Slow Rock Ballad example that feels closer to this piece.
I recommend viewing the whole Jazz Fundamentals: What Is Swing? video to hear a typical Swing bassline (which is 4 beats without triples) while it's the melody (saxophone in this video) that is in triplets with the piano providing off beat and syncopated accents.  But in "I Know It's Over" the bassline has a much slower constantly occurring quarter-note + eighth-note rhythm, which is not typical Swing that has lots of syncopation and much more accented off-beats (the 2nd and the 4th).

There's a lot of triplets.  I'd probably notate this in 12/8 or with actual triplets rather than using straight 8s and 'swing'.




Whether this bass line is an example, or a good example, of swing rhythm can depend on what we’re asking. The terminology is not always clear and if we’re being instructed to apply the term correctly for a particular style of music then there’s plenty of room for pedantry.
In general swing and other kinds of long-short rhythm patterns are contrasted to straight 1-2-3-4 patterns which are great for marching soldiers but less good for dancing. Most kinds of music include departures from an even beat, and folk and gypsy music can simply flaunt the idea of keeping a metronomic time which makes it rather hard to notate accurately. The word ‘swing’ along with ‘groove’ and other hip words comes from Jazz and I suppose that a case could be made that talking about swing rhythms really belongs to the world of the swing era in Jazz. There it is not just about playing the second note of a note pair with a delay but also about doing it so artfully that the listener feels taken in by the groove. Rather like making the music dance for the ears we could say. The exact delay depends on the tempo - with drummers usually playing more evenly when they play faster.
Using the term ‘swing’ more generally for long short-patterns such as the one in the bass line of this song is quite common in my experience. There is good info on defining and notating swing here: What is the difference between swing and shuffle? This gets quite interesting when it is not just the timing that drifts away from an even beat count but varying accents and harmony are used to emphasise particular beats or off-beats in the bar too. What name we then apply to the feel can depend on the genre.
What I hear at the start of the song is a strong swing in the bass which contrasts with the drummer playing pretty straight. Having one instrument play straight while another plays with a swing is common in pop music, as is swapping from straight to swing feel in different sections, or even in one bar. Jimi Hendrix was good at this.
The Smiths do not all swing along with the bass at the start and as the song goes on there are changes so that some sections have a more straight feel in the bass. This is partly because the bass line gets more busy. For someone learning the song or writing similar bass lines it is a great exercise not just to play along but also try to notate it as exactly as possible. Modern tools allow us to analyse the timing of various instruments with amazing precision!
